# "Failure talking to yum: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: remi"

Tags: ansible, centos7

I am using the following ansible script to install php-fpm module in centOS but cannot figure out the error.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:

    - name: download remi release repo for php
      get_url:
            url: http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
            dest: /tmp/remi-release-6.rpm

      tags: php-fpm

    - name: install remi repo
      shell: /bin/rpm -Uvh /tmp/remi-release-6.rpm
      register: remi_repo_result
      failed_when: "'conflict' in remi_repo_result.stderr"
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: enable remi repo
      ini_file: dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
          section=remi
          option=enabled
          value=1

    - name: install php-fpm and its deps
      yum: name={{item}} state=present
      with_items:
      - php
      - php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: backup default php configuration
      shell: /bin/cp /etc/php.ini /etc/php.default.ini creates=/etc/php.default.ini
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: display php errors when not in production
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php.ini
         section=PHP
         option=display_errors
         value=On
      when: env is defined and env != "production"
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: do not show php errors when in production
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php.ini
          section=PHP
          option=display_errors
          value=Off
      when: env is defined and env == "production"
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: backup default php-fpm configuration
      shell: /bin/cp /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default creates=/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: change php-fpm to listen on socket
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
          section=www
          option=listen
          value=/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: php-fpm listen mode should always be 0666
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
          section=www
          option=listen.mode
          value=0666
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: change php-fpm user
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
          section=www
          option=user
          value=nginx
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: change php-fpm group
      ini_file: dest=/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
          section=www
          option=group
          value=nginx
      notify:
      - restart php-fpm
      tags: php-fpm

    - name: start php-fpm
      service: name=php-fpm state=running enabled=yes
      tags: php-fpm
```

I get the following error in the task **"install php-fpm and its deps"**

failed: [127.0.0.1] (item=[u'php', u'php-fpm']) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": ["php", "php-fpm"], "msg": "Failure talking to yum: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: remi"}

Can someone help with a solution for this?

Comment: 1/ EL-6 is dead, have reached its EOL some weeks ago.

BTW, cannot reproduce...

Comment: Ensure you are using the proper configuration package, see https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/, and also EPEL

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`? Error seems to indicate that there is no `baseurl` for `[remi]` repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: most of the below is deduced from wild guesses since you did not provide a full and verbose run of the relevant tasks nor the values of the variables for the target you run the playbook against.

There are several issues with your above playbook, the most obvious and relevant one being that

```yaml
    - name: install remi repo
      shell: /bin/rpm -Uvh /tmp/remi-release-6.rpm
      register: remi_repo_result
      failed_when: "'conflict' in remi_repo_result.stderr"
      tags: php-fpm
```

is likelly to **not fail** although the command **is in error**.

And since you did not use [`create: false`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html#parameter-create) on the next `ini_file` task, `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` will still be created containing only

```
[remi]
enabled=1
```

(For this, I am of course assuming that `env` is not set or is different from `production`)

From there, the message you get is quite coherent since there is literally no base url for repo `remi`.

Some other notes you might want to take into account:

1. you can install a remote rpm with the `yum` module by directly passing the url as `name`
2. you should not loop over the `yum` module: pass the list of packages directly in the name attribute (see [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes))
3. don't `cp` with shell, use the `copy` module with `remote_src: true`
4. Use the yaml syntax rather than ini style shortcut syntax